# Chrome Extension | how to organize long-lived connection correctly?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, messaging

I'm building a chrome extension and it consists of two files: content script and background script. When some events happen on the page my content script listens to them and reacts by sending a message to background script. Code extract from content file:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "knockknock"});
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {

    });
...
function onMouseUp () {
   ...
   port.postMessage({message: important});
   ...
}
```

Code extract from background:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        if (msg.message)
            doSomething(msg.message);
    });
});
```

This works OK and my background gets the message.

Then it must create its own message and send it to content script. And here is the problem. Inside my `doSomething()` function i have one more function `doSomethingMore()` where I pass the message too. As this function is inside `doSomething()` function and `doSomething()` function is inside `port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {}`  as far as I understand such code like this `port.postMessage({newMessage: importantToo});` must work but it doesn't.

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        if (msg.message)
            doSomething(msg.message);
    });
});

function doSomething(mes) {
    ...
    doSomethingMOre(mes);
}
function doSomethingMore(message) {
    ...
}
```

I guess opening a new port is a bad idea. But maybe someone knows how to pass my message correctly?
Thanks a lot in advance!